# GroupBy and plot with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have data.
There are some groups of people who participate in the meetings. Meetings are divided into speeches. Each meeting and speeches combination has a number of participants. The number of participants in one meeting does not change. In other words, the number of participants only changes from meeting to meeting.

```
data = [
 ['group_1', 1, 1, 68],
 ['group_2', 1, 1, 35],
 ['group_1', 1, 2, 68],
 ['group_2', 1, 2, 35],
 ['group_1', 2, 1, 78],
 ['group_2', 2, 1, 25],
 ['group_1', 2, 2, 78], 
 ['group_2', 2, 2, 25],
 ['group_1', 3, 1, 73], 
 ['group_2', 3, 1, 30],
 ['group_1', 3, 2, 73], 
 ['group_2', 3, 2, 30]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['group_name', 'meeting', 'present', 'members'])
```

X is meeting, y is number of participants. I want to plot something like this.

```
df.groupby(['group_name']).plot(
         x='meeting', y='members',
         color='#4b0082', linewidth=3,
         marker='h', markerfacecolor='lightgreen', markeredgewidth=1, markersize=9, markevery=1);
```

[image]

However, I would like to add a title as a group name and sign the y-axis. and I also have a problem when I run this code on all data, for some reason I have extra points on the plot.
[image]

On the first graph the count should start from meeting 27 and there is an anomaly in meeting area 40. On the second graph there are anomalies in a 27 meeting area.

Comment: What is your pandas version? `print(pd.__version__)`?

Comment: pandas version is 1.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `pandas >= 1.1.0` we have the `ylabel` argument in [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). Also we will rewrite your groupby a bit so we can access the group name:

```
for grp, d in df.groupby('group_name'):
    d.plot(
        x='meeting',
        y='members',
        color='#4b0082',
        ylabel='members',
        title=grp,
        linewidth=3,
        marker='h',
        markerfacecolor='lightgreen',
        markeredgewidth=1,
        markersize=9,
        markevery=1
    )
```

[image: plots]

Comment: But i still have problem with extra point. I decided to do one more grouping and take a mean for each meeting.

for grp, d in df.groupby('group_name'): 
       d.groupby('meeting').mean()['members'].plot(title=grp)

This is what I need, however, I ran into the problem that all graphics are displayed in one form. I would like to separate them as it was before